# CSV parsed in php wont allow me to use any math functions on parts of the table

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, csv

I am trying to process a CSV file, pull the individual columns out, do some math, then store it to a database...  I can do everything but the math part...

Here is the base code I currently have:

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
$i = 0;
while ( !feof($fp) )
{
    $data = fgetcsv($fp,0,"\t");
    print_r($data);
        if(!empty($data[6])){
            $url = explode('.',$data[0]);
            //$math = floor((($data[6]* 100)* .5)) / 100;
            $math = $data[6] * 100;
            echo '' . trim($data[6]) . '<br /> ' . $math;


        }

}
```

I have tried using `(float)`, `trim`, `number_format` on the data, and it returns 0 each time.
I have tried using `fgetcsv`, `str_getcsv`, and `explode` on \n\r the \t
I tried even shoving into into a mysql database, using decimal, and float, and both put a 0 value in.  I added it as a varchar, tried pulling it back out then re-did all the above, and it still always returns 0....

Is there another way to process this data? is there some encoding I need to set?

Here is a copy/paste from the file (few things changes), its tab delimited

```
url.url.com    50   1   2.00%   0.29    5.87    0.29
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take your input file and do `cat input_file | hexdump -C | less` and look for that seventh value. Is the decimal point represented by a single `2e` character, or something else? Namely something that's not an ASCII decimal, but renders like one.

Comment: doing a bin2hex() on the field I am getting: 0030002e00320039000d00   it looks like the decimal is 2e but there are to many 0's?  when I tried to isolate the decimal it always returned 0... (tried `substr($data[6],1,1)` then `substr($data[6],0,3)` and both gave me '0')

Comment: that's exactly what it was!   there was 2 0's being added between each piece,  I did a substr('00','',$hex) on the hex value and converted it back to a string, and can now process it as a number... not sure if there is a better way but this seems to work... hopefully in all cases...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //$math = floor((($data[6]* 100)* .5)) / 100;

Given the value is 0.29 in the example
the following will happen

0.29 * 100 => 29.0
29.0 * .5 => 14.5
floor( 14.5 ) => 14 (as an integer)
14 / 100 => (an integer divide operation)  yields 0

To obtain a non 0 result, either the original value must be quite large
or, preferably, ALL factors be float values I.E.

$math = floor((($data[6]* 100.0)* .5)) / 100.0;
```